# What's the difference between GC and FontData for getting font height?

Tags: java, fonts, swt, font-size

This explains font metrics
[image]

I think we can get "Font height" in SWT like these;

```
GC gc = new GC(label);
System.out.println( gc.textExtent(label.getText()) );
System.out.println( label.getFont().getFontData()[0].getHeight() );
```

Why this two outs aren't same? And which one is correct height for a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GC#textExtent()` returns extent in *pixels*, while `FontData` returns in font *points*. The units are different here.

Comment: Actually not exactly sure but I would just loop through font heights until I achieve the pixel height I require.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't seem like convenient approach.

Comment: @miqbal: you can get the system DPI with `Device.getDPI()`, eg `pixels = points * Device.getDPI() / 72`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: `Device.getDPI()` returns a `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FontMetrics.getHeight()` to get height in pixels.

```
FontMetrics fontMetrics = gc.getFontMetrics()
```

Comment: The problem with using this method is if the text contains any returns. Using textExtent would include the pixels for multiple lines.