# How to use freetypegl with {0, w, h, 0} ortho projection?

Tags: c++, opengl, text, projection, freetype

freetypegl is written to work with {0, w, 0, h) projection, almost all demos included to this library work with that projection. I prefere {0, w, h, 0} and I do not know how to change the code to be able to work with that ortho. I tried to reverse uvs, but then text is aligned to upper bound and it does not look good.

**How can I change the code to work with {0, w, h, 0} projection?**

```
void AddGlyph(Vector2& position, const char c, uint color, texture_font_t* ftFont)
{
    texture_glyph_t* glyph = texture_font_get_glyph(ftFont, &c);
    if (c) {
        if (string) {
            position.x += texture_glyph_get_kerning(glyph, &c- 1) * scale;
        }

        //One glyph is a quad and quad has 4 vertices and 6 elements, 
        //it does not impact the case
        MapBuffer(4, 6);

        float x0 = position.x + static_cast<float>(glyph->offset_x),
              y0 = position.y + static_cast<float>(glyph->offset_y),
              x1 = x0 + static_cast<float>(glyph->width),
              y1 = y0 - static_cast<float>(glyph->height),

              u0 = glyph->s0,
              v0 = glyph->t0,
              u1 = glyph->s1,
              v1 = glyph->t1;

        //vertex struct is position, uv, color
        AddVertexData(Vector2(x0, y0), Vector2(u0, v0), color);
        AddVertexData(Vector2(x0, y1), Vector2(u0, v1), color);
        AddVertexData(Vector2(x1, y1), Vector2(u1, v1), color);
        AddVertexData(Vector2(x1, y0), Vector2(u1, v0), color);

        //default rectangle elements dependence
        AddRectElements();

        position.x += glyph->advance_x * scale;
    }
}

void DrawString(const std::string& text, Vector2& position, uint color, const Font& font)
{
    using namespace ftgl;
    texture_font_t* ftFont = font.getFTFont();

    for (const auto& c : text) {
        AddGlyph(position, c, color, ftFont);
    } 
}
```

Maybe I should change library code? If so, what should I change?

Comment: _I tried to reverse uvs_ How did you try to reverse the uvs? IMHO, it would be sufficient to change lines `v0 = glyph->t0` and `v1 = glyph->t1` into `v0 = glyph->t1` and `v1 = glyph->t0` as this should result in a vertically mirrored texture mapping. Or is this what you tried and it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I tried.

Comment: May be, the rect reflects exactly the area covered by glyph. Hence, mirroring v means that the base lines of glyphs don't match anymore. So, you have to change y respectively. What, if you leave uvs as is but change `y1 = y0 - static_cast<float>(glyph->height),` to `y1 = y0 + static_cast<float>(glyph->height),`? Please, be aware that this changes orientation of quads. So, you might have to adjust face culling. May be, it's better to disable it until you got this right.

Comment: Nope, it looks a bit different than after uvs change, but it is still not correct.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. Changing projection {0, w, 0, h} to {0, w, h, 0} means that the y axis points into reverse direction. Reversing y should reverse the effect again. Of couse, I don't know how you get the y. If it went from 0 ... h with original projection, it has to go from h ... 0 with vertical reversed projection. (It's a matter of fact that text lines go from top to down in western european culture.) ;-) Furthermore, the line of height might have to be considered as well (i.e. an additional offset might be necessary to reversed y)...

Comment: Hmm. May be, I didn't consider `glyph->offset_y` seriously. How about `y0 = position.y - static_cast<float>(glyph->offset_y)` **and** `y1 = y0 + static_cast<float>(glyph->height)`?

Comment: Yep, I just thought the same. It is almost ok, but now there is a problem with position. I mean, when projection is {0, w, h, 0} and we set text posititon to be {0, 0} it should be fully visible with 0, 0 pointing at the left top of the text, it accutualy points at bottom left, so I should add text height like this:

`y0 = position.y - static_cast<float>(glyph->offset_y) + glyph->height` and it goes back to wierd alignment.

Comment: Yeah, `glyph->height` is the wrong thing for this. This is what I realized (after 2nd or 3rd comment): the glyph heights vary. Glyph offset and height are set so that corresponding texture needs to cover only the "non-white" parts of the glyph. Glyph height is not line height. The line height should be available somewhere else. Alternatively, you can get the offset and height of a glyph which covers the whole vertical range of line, may be, the '|' or the '§'. Better is, of course, to retrieve the line height from the font description. It should be available somewhere.

Comment: As I take a look everyday at demos included to freetypegl, it looks as if line height is = font size. I think it also should be good if we add offset to height and it should get the proper glyph height. But demonstration projects use font size as a line height.

Comment: And, does it work with font size as a line height?

Comment: Not in my case, it is ~20px too big.

Comment: I don't believe that _add offset to height_ is a correct alternative. Please, consider e.g. the glyphs for `g`, `x`, `M`. Compare the bounding rect of these glyphs with the relative position of base line. For `x` and `M`, it's at the bottom but for `g` somewhere in the lower half. The height is probably just the height of the bounding rect. It might be similar for `g` and `M` but is much smaller for `x`.

Comment: There is doc. for freetypegl, I just found on github. Unfortunately, it's doxygen based i.e. has to be built. However, I found this image which supports my last comment: [Glyph metrics](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/blob/master/doc/images/glyph.png)

Comment: After digging a bit in [freetype-gl on github](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl), I found `texture_font_t.height` in [texture-font.h:282](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/blob/7a290ac372d2bd94137a9fed6b2f5a6ac4360ec2/texture-font.h#L282):

Comment: `/** This field is simply used to compute a default line spacing (i.e., the baseline-to-baseline distance) when writing text with this font. Note that it usually is larger than the sum of the ascender and descender taken as absolute values. There is also no guarantee that no glyphs extend above or below subsequent baselines when using this distance. */`

Comment: And this gives a hint that `ascender + descender` is the other candidate that I was not aware about. These are the heights over and under base line, hence, the sum is the line height. You find them in the same header a few lines below.

Comment: Yes! ` y0 = position.y - static_cast<float>(glyph->offset_y) + (ftFont->ascender + ftFont->descender)` works! I am wondering what is ascender and descender, I do not exactly understand. I found wikipedia formula, but it is a bit unclear for me.

Comment: I guess the essential missing piece was that you was not aware that the base line is the line were glyphs like `x` and `M` "sit on". Some glyphs (like e.g. `g` and `y`) stretch below. So, concerning the vertical line range, descend is the range from bottom to base line, ascend the range from base line to top of line, and, hence, ascend + descend the line height. Then, there is the distance from base line to next base line which considers also the white space between lines. So, the height is a bit larger then line height. Glyph coordinates are usually given relative to base line (vertically).

Comment: I just found another question with a nice image which might be of help: [SO: What's the difference between GC and FontData for getting font height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13604492/7478597).

Comment: Thank you very much for help :)